# Center website in each section dinamically html5 js

Tags: javascript, css, html

im trying to make a website that center automatically the scroll in each section, for example:

```
<body>
  <div id="section1" style="height:100vh;"></div>
  <div id="section2" style="height:100vh;"></div>
  <div id="section3" style="height:100vh;"></div>
</body>
```

so, when you are watching the first seccion, the website center you window in mid of section1, if you scroll for bottom, it changes centerin now section2, im not sure if im explaining what im trying to do, but thats the idea, thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried? What seems to be the issue? All you have here is a few div tags...

Comment: You are searching for a plugin like `fullPage.js`. I recommend you a plugin because if you don't know how to start that development, I think you don't achieve nothing, so with a plugin all the work is making instead of you. See this: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ And this question should be closed as offtopic.

Comment: thanks! thats all I need!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck!